# Clickhouse in_order loadbalancing does not seem to work as expected

Tags: clickhouse

I have a single shard clickhouse setup with 2 replicas. I tried in_order and first_or_randome loadbalancing. But when I check the query_log table in system schema, it seem to show the queries are actually going into both replicas on a distributed table and not the first replica (assuming there are no clickhouse errors at the moment)

I have the following table:

- test_table_buffer (buffer table to which data is written)
- test_table (Replicated Table)
- test_table_distributed (Distributed table).

I don't need a distributed table theoretically because I have only one shard. I created only for the sake of testing.

Query Log on first replica:

```sql
┌──────────event_time─┬─query─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ 2022-09-03 08:28:26 │ SELECT count(1) FROM test_table_distributed WHERE __created_at >= '2022-09-03 08:28:20' │
│ 2022-09-03 08:28:25 │ SELECT count(1) FROM test_table_distributed WHERE __created_at >= '2022-09-03 08:28:20' │
│ 2022-09-03 08:28:20 │ INSERT INTO test_table_distributed VALUES                                               │
│ 2022-09-03 08:28:20 │ INSERT INTO test_table_distributed VALUES                                               │
```

On replica 2

```sql
┌──────────event_time─┬─query───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ 2022-09-03 08:28:33 │ INSERT INTO test_table_distributed VALUES                                               │
│ 2022-09-03 08:28:32 │ SELECT count(1) FROM test_table_distributed WHERE __created_at >= 
  2022-09-03 08:28:26 │
│ 2022-09-03 08:28:32 │ INSERT INTO test_table_distributed VALUES                                               │
│ 2022-09-03 08:28:31 │ SELECT count(1) FROM test_table_distributed WHERE __created_at >= 
 2022-09-03 08:28:26 │
│ 2022-09-03 08:28:26 │ INSERT INTO test_table_distributed VALUES                                               │
│ 2022-09-03 08:28:26 │ INSERT INTO test_table_distributed VALUES                                               │
│ 2022-09-03 08:28:13 │ SELECT count(1) FROM test_table_distributed WHERE __created_at >= '2022-09-03 08:28:07' │
│ 2022-09-03 08:28:13 │ SELECT count(1) FROM test_table_distributed WHERE __created_at >= '2022-09-03 08:28:07' │
```

Seems like the select queries are going to both from above log and not just to first replica.

The use-case is that we need a consistent read immediately after write for few use-cases and not eventual consistency. So it's okay to write to first replica available and be able to read from the same. If the other replica eventually consistent with replication, it's okay.

Comment: which replica do you use to run your `SELECT count(1) FROM test_table_distributed WHERE ...` query?

Are you sure you have the same `remote_servers` `<replica>` order in your shard on all servers?

Is your `test_table_distributed` table have  `to test_table_buffer` in `Engine=Distributed(...)` section?

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting [prefer_localhost_replica](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#settings-prefer-localhost-replica)

You need to disable it.

```xml
cat /etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/prefer_localhost_replica.xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<yandex>
    <profiles>
        <default>
            <prefer_localhost_replica>0</prefer_localhost_replica>
        </default>
    </profiles>
</yandex>
```

Comment: Thanks Denny. Let me try that.